# Timestamp Python Pandas KeyError: 'timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to plot minute data from Tesla stock

And I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minutiniai.py", line 12, in <module>
    d.head(100).plot(x='timestamp',y=['open','close'],figsize=(10,5))
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 914, in __call__
    elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'timestamp'
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file_name = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Finansinis/TSLA_1min.csv'
d = pn.read_csv(file_name)
print(d.head(10))

d.head(100).plot(x='timestamp',y=['open','close'],figsize=(10,5))

plt.title("Minute data")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Dates")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
tick_idx = plt.xticks()[0]

plt.show()
```

Could anyone help me figure out what the issue might be?

Comment: try `x= d['timestamp']`,`y=[d['open'],d['close']]`.......if the error furter exist this means your dataframe `d` doesn't have timestamp named column

Comment: first make sure your dataframe has a column named 'timestamp'

Comment: Thank you guys! I am so dumb.. The column in the dataframe didn't have name timestamp..